# Unable to pass state parameters to mutation

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I read documentation about `Apollo graphql client` but still have some questions combining `Apollo` and `react`.

Consider, we have simple form with 4 fields with submit button. Once submit is pressed, values from the fields are saved to `this.state.data` (double checked that this is saved correctly).

On the backend, I have a `mutation` like: `userCreate(input: UserInput): User` which definetly takes this field inputs.

The problem is:

> How to execute mutation properly binding values from a `this.state.data` fields?

As of this moment I have following code:

```
onChange = e =>
    this.setState({
      data: { ...this.state.data, [e.target.id]: e.target.value }
    });

  handleSubmit = async () => {
    writeToLog(this.state.data)
    const { name, email, externalId, userCode} = this.state.data
    this.props.userCreateQuery({
      input: {
        name,
        email,
        externalId,
        userCode
      }
    })
  }
```

this is how mutation looks like:

```
const QUERY_PERSON_MUTATION = gql`
mutation userCreateQuery($name: String!, $email: String!, $externalId: String!, $userCode: String!) {
  userCreate(input: {
    Name: $name,
    Email: $email,
    ExternalId: $externalId,
    UserCode: $userCode}) {
    Name
    Email
    ExternalId
    UserCode
  }
}`;
```

component wrapup:

```
const NewUserFormWithData = graphql(QUERY_PERSON_MUTATION, { name: 'userCreateQuery' })(NewUserForm);

    export default withApollo(NewUserFormWithData)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Schema:

```
const typeDefs = `
type User {
   UserId: Int
   /* other fields */
}

input UserInput {
   UserId: Int
   UserCode: String
   /* other fields */
}

type Mutation {
   userCreate(input: UserInput): User
   userUpdate(userId: Int, input: UserInput): User    
}`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your data inside the variables key:

```
this.props.userCreateQuery({
  variables: {
      input: {
        name,
        email,
        externalId,
        userCode
      }
  }
})
```

PS.: I do not know your graphql server, but you maybe not use the key input to your mutation works.

What about we've discussed:

Your mutation with the key input.

```
 const QUERY_PERSON_MUTATION = gql`
    mutation userCreateQuery($name: String!, $email: String!, $externalId: String!, $userCode: String!) {
      userCreate(
        Name: $name,
        Email: $email,
        ExternalId: $externalId,
        UserCode: $userCode) {
        Name
        Email
        ExternalId
        UserCode
      }
    }`;

this.props.userCreateQuery({
  variables: {
      name,
      email,
      externalId,
      userCode
  }
})
```

Comment: This is the first thing I tried, but for some reason, it failed.  Same for now. It does compile but does not execute.

Comment: Also, what does 'the key input to your mutation' mean? Please clarify.

Comment: the 'key input' means nothing for me, I just use your object. I you do not have the key input on your graphql schema, you must remove the input to your mutation works

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but this is what I can provide.  I just played around with your code still no progress.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your graphql schema?

Comment: Ok, I will check right now. Your mutation worked at graphqil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162997/discussion-between-reborn-and-alessander-franca).